# Angular (with typescript) builds XML-Tree in wrong order

Tags: angular, typescript, xml-parsing

In Angular I have written the following code which is supposed to create an XML-Document which can then be sent to an external API.

```js
range(1, newTabAmount + 1).subscribe(x => {
    templateData.forEach((templateDataElement, i) => {
        if (i !== 0) {
            //clone intial item
            const item: XMLDocument = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('a:ChangeSetEntry')[0];
            const target: XMLDocument = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('changeSet')[0];
            const clone: Node = item.cloneNode(true);

            target.appendChild(clone);
        }

        const changeSetEntry: any = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('a:ChangeSetEntry')[i];

        const entity: XMLDocument = changeSetEntry.getElementsByTagName('a:Entity')[0];

        console.log('repeat-position: ' + (newTabStartId + x));
        entity.getElementsByTagName('c:RepeatPosition')[0].textContent = String(newTabStartId + x); //set amout of tab you want to add
        entity.getElementsByTagName('c:MetaAttributeKey')[0].textContent = String(templateDataElement.MetaAttributeKey);
        entity.getElementsByTagName('c:ReferenceKey')[0].textContent = String(referenceKey);


        console.log('current id: ' + curId);
        console.log('iterator;' + idIterator);
        changeSetEntry.getElementsByTagName('a:Id')[0].textContent = String(idIterator);
        changeSetEntry.getElementsByTagName('a:Operation')[0].textContent = 'Insert';

        ++idIterator;
    });
});
```

This code gives me the following output:

> ```
> > repeat-position: 11 iterator;0 repeat-position: 11 iterator;1
> > repeat-position: 11 iterator;2 repeat-position: 11 iterator;3
> > repeat-position: 12 iterator;4 repeat-position: 12 iterator;5
> > repeat-position: 12 iterator;6 repeat-position: 12 iterator;7
> > repeat-position: 13 iterator;8 repeat-position: 13 iterator;9
> > repeat-position: 13 iterator;10 repeat-position: 13 iterator;11
> > repeat-position: 14 iterator;12 repeat-position: 14 iterator;13
> > repeat-position: 14 iterator;14 repeat-position: 14 iterator;15
> > request started...
> ```

And additionally I get an XML-Document as output which strangely has a completely different order compared to the console.log() - Outputs.

XML-Output in Google Chrome:
[image: XML-Output in Google Chrome]

Interesting is that the first 4 elements (the come form the first iteration of the inner loop) have a valid Id. But the next 4 elements all have the value 4 and (I haven't added this otherwise the screenshot would've been too big) from iteration 8 to 12 all elements have the Id 8. Do you have any idea why the order is different in the XML-document compared to the console.log() output? I have no explanation for this unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem:

```
        range(1, newTabAmount).subscribe(x => {
        templateData.forEach((templateDataElement, i) => {
            const xmlRawDataElement: any = {};

            xmlRawDataElement.repeatPos = newTabStartId + x;
            xmlRawDataElement.Id = idIterator;

            xmlRawData.push(xmlRawDataElement);

            ++idIterator;
        });
    });
```

By building an assingnable model first and then applying it to my XML-model it works. I assume that because the XML-DOM operation take some time angular tries to perform the other tasks in another thread even if the neccessary variables for the next step aren't set properly yet. So if you encounter the same problem with wrong order try to build the gist of your XML-Model in a small JSON at first and assing it afterwards if you have calculated everything properly :)